# Attempting to learn React and Javascript but stuck on this strange syntax for map and passing an anonymous function to it

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This came from the [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) itself. I'm a C# developer diving into web development and some of the Javascript syntax is just baffling to me.

History itself is an array of size 9.

A few questions:

1. What is step and why is it not being used or referenced anywhere? This is the extent of this function and I'm really not sure what's going on with those parameters
2. What does map do with that anonymous function exactly?
3. What is moves? Is it an array? What does this returning of a list item do exactly?

```
    const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
      const desc = move ?
        'Go to move #' + move :
        'Go to game start';
      return (
        <li>
          <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
        </li>
      );
    });
```

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation for [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?. The second parameter to the callback is the index of the element. The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at this step by step.

`const moves = history.map()`

What do we know here? We know that we are defining a constant called `moves` to hold an iterated returned values of an array called `history`. How do we know `history` is an array? Because `.map` is a JS prototype function / shorthand for `for (let i = 0; i < history.length; i +=1) ...`

Further on, we create an anonymous function, right inside the called `.map()` function, like this:

`const moves = history.map((step, move) => ...`

What is `step` and what is `move`? This is more commonly named `value` and `index`. And the naming does not matter, this is a function parameter name, and we can call it however it is clear for us.

Let's write it like this:

`const moves = history.map((value, index) => ...` Maybe it makes some more sense now? `value` is the well, value of the array item, and index is its position.

`.map()` is a shorthand prototype for providing us with quick iteration over values and its mapped index.

so, let's say `history = ['/login', '/logout', '/home]`

`history.map((value, index) => console.log(value, index))` would give us `'/login', 0` `/logout, 1`, `/home 2`

We can completely omit `step / index` parameter as well, it is optional (so is the `value` parameter but you mostly want to work with it.)

Now what does it `return` ? It returns a HTML / JSX (in React case) element using the values generated from the array.

We could also write it like this (Maybe more similar to plain Vanilla JS will trigger some C# similarities):

```
const moves = []

  for (let i = 0; i < history.length; i += 1) {
    const step = history[i]
    const move = i

    const desc = move ? `Go to move #${move}` : 'Go to game start'
    moves.push(
      <li>
        <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
      </li>
    )
  }

  return <ol>{moves}</ol>
```

Result:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(0)}>Go to move #0</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(1)}>Go to move #1</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(2)}>Go to move #2</button>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Ahh, removing the shorthand really helped a lot. And renaming (step, move) to (value, index) makes a lot more sense. Thanks so much for this detailed explanation! I definitely understand what's happening here now.

Comment: Glad I could be of help! I would highly recommend taking a brief look at ES6 / Vanilla JS tricks and introductions while you are working on React as well, just so you don't get de-motivated thinking React is confusing when in fact its just another ES6 / JS shorthand :) Have a nice time learning!

Answer (score 0):

Map function gets element and its index in arguments, so if you want to get only index you need to name first argument(element) somehow, convention is to use `_` as a name for unused variable. So `step` is element from history array, and move is it's index

Map calls that function with every element of that array passing element as first argument and index as second argument, returned value is used in returned array.

Example:

```js
const a = [1,2,3];
const b = a.map(element => element*2); // b = [2,4,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

`.map` is a helper function for creating a new array based on an old one. You pass in a function which describes how to do the conversion. Your function will then be called multiple times, once for each element of the array, and the return values are used to construct the new array.

The function will get passed in 3 arguments: an element of the array, the index of that element, and the entire array. In the code snippet you provided, that first argument has been named `step`, the second one `move`, and the third one is being ignored.

With that description in mind, here's the answers to your individual questions:

> What is step

The value in the array. So the first time the function is called, it's the value at `history[0]`. Next time, it's `history[1]`.

> why is it not being used or referenced anywhere

The author of the code didn't need it. They still need to give it a name, but that's only so they can then give a name to the second argument which is the one they really care about.

> What does map do with that anonymous function exactly?

It will call the function once for each element of `history`, and use the return values to create `moves`

> What is moves? Is it an array?

Yes, it's an array of objects. Those objects describe to React what the page is supposed to look like.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to understand this better now. Thank you for the explanation!